# Can having too many noindex pages hurt ranking?

Tags: seo, google, ranking, noindex

Can having too many noindex pages hurt ranking?

Eg: 50,000 low quality noindex forum posts with 1,000 indexed quality posts.

Can those 50,000 low quality noindex forum posts affect for 1,000 indexed quality postsranking?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there differences between deleting low quality articles vs no-indexing low quality articles SEO wise?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/111290/is-there-differences-between-deleting-low-quality-articles-vs-no-indexing-low-qu)

Answer (score 0):

google may be not happy if you had est chose pour content in its index and if google had loose time while crawling ans trying to index it.

Here you decided to prevent from that, so don't worry.
My advice : may be what you think is poor content is not and is a huge page rank amount sleeping, so put it on another subdomain to fully separate it and let google index this subdomain. If you like it after one or 2 month, you'll know what to do with it !